# laravel json response returns raw data to the browser even though i have not dump the results

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to retrieve data from the database using laravel's JSON response, but i get a raw data displaying in the browser.

i am getting the response being dumped in the  browser, nothing else is displayed. i want to retrieve the data using axios in my vue template.

The data is rather dump in the browser instead of being return as an HTTP response

```
 { "id":1,"fee":"0.00","attendance":"0.00","library":"CLEARED","created_at":"2019-10-19 19:16:08","updated_at":"2019-10-19 19:16:08"}
```

sample code from my controller

```
 public function index()
 {
    $clearancevalidator = ClearanceValidator::all()->first();

    return response()->json($clearancevalidator);
 }
```

this is my route

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'clearancevalidators'], function(){
        Route::get('/', 'Admin\ClearanceValidatorController@index')
            ->name('admin.clearancevalidators.index');
    });
```

Comment: This is not an error or a bug, it should work like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only access the data with Axios in your Javascript or Postman and not see them in the browser, you can do this (not bulletproof)

```php
public function index()
{
    if (request()->wantsJson()) {
      $clearancevalidator = ClearanceValidator::all()->first();

      return response()->json($clearancevalidator);
    }
    return 'You shall not see this in the browser';
}
```

And in your Vue component, make a simple Ajax get request with axios

```js
export default {
    mounted() {
        axios.get("/clearancevalidators").then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
};
```

#### You can see the data in the network tab under XHR section

[image]

> Browsers can still just add an `application/json` header to get the data

Hope this helps

Comment: You just said you don't want to see the data in the browser :') make your mind please

Comment: Updated with an example Vue component

Comment: the data is not display in the network XHR, i change the browse to firefox it displays as JSON or Raw Data. do i post a screen shot

Comment: "You shall not see this in the browser" display alright, but the json data is not found in the network  -> XHR -> Preview as it is in your image

Comment: My image is when using the Ajax in Vue component, are you using Vue yet?

Comment: used the default example template in vue and import it in a index.blade, but when the controller sends the json response, nothing shows except the raw data. not even my html

Comment: DO NOT VISIT THE URL VIA THE BROWSER, use Ajax to do it, show your Vue component and the `index.blade`

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is how the data is displayed nothing in the network XHR,i try firefox i got the same reponse